# Can someone explain why the answer is B? I'm using Java and I don't understand

Tags: java, math

Which of the following statements are the same?

(I) x -= x + 4

(II) x = x + 4 - x

(III) x = x - (x + 4)

A. (I) and (II) are the same

B. (I) and (III) are the same

C. (II) and (III) are the same

D. (I), (II), and (III) are the same

Comment: I believe II and II are the same

Comment: See Compound operator in java,http://java.about.com/od/c/g/compoundassgnment.htm

Answer (score 6):

```
x -= y is equivalent to x = x - y
```

Therefore

```
x -= x + 4
```

is equivalent to

```
x = x - (x+4)
```

So assuming `(II) x = x - (x + 4)` was supposed to be `(III) x = x - (x + 4)` (since you have two options marked as `(II)`), `(I)` and `(III)` are the same.

Comment: Please note that `(II)` won't compile if the type of `x` is smaller than `int` (byte, char, short). Math operators like `+` will "upgrade" them to `int`, perform the operation, and try to store the result (still of type `int`) into `x`, which will upset the compiler. On the other hand, compound operators like `-=` (in solution `(I)`) automatically add a cast, so the compiler is OK (but then you may have a problem with overflow at runtime).

Answer (score 3):

It's because of operator precedence.  Java evaluates that as if it were

x -= (x+4)

so it first computes `(x+4)` and then subtracts that from `x` -- which is what the `-` part of `-=` means -- and then updates `x`, which is what the `=` part means.

Answer (score 1):

- Case (I) expands to x = x − (x + 4) according to the Java `-=` operator,
  and mathematically simplifies to x = −4.
- Case (II) mathematically simplifies to x = 4.
- Case (III) mathematically simplifies to x = −4.

Therefore (I) and (III) are the same, which means the answer is (B).

Answer (score 0):

`-=` is a so called compound assignment.

Those are just short-cuts and combine atomic operations.

`x -= y` stands for `x = x-y`

`x += y` stands for `x = x+y`

`x++` stands for `x = x+1`

`x--` stands for `x = x-1`

There also are ++x and --x which do the same as x++ / x-- except that they return the value of x **before** it is incremented / decremented.

Official Java tutorial:

> "You can also combine the arithmetic operators with the simple
>   assignment operator to create compound assignments. For example, x+=1;
>   and x=x+1; both increment the value of x by 1."

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html

I think the same works for `*=`, `/=` and `%=`

Comment: AFAIK non of these operations is atomic.

Comment: I didn't claim that they are. I claimed that they are compund out of atomic operations.

Comment: Example: `x++` is compund out of the atomic operations: 

1. read x 

2. increase x by 1

3. write x back to the memory